# Meteor FindOne, Find

Tags: mongodb, meteor, find

Im trying to make a query to my mongoDB from my Meteor application.

My mongo collection looks like:

`{
    "_id" : "ZfHCLZF4fC3e99PTs",
    "author" : "admin",
    "dishes" : [ 
        {
            "dishId" : "ASxbTyAe3CrKuNPF4",
            "name" : "Gaseosa",
            "price" : "2000",
            "quantity" : 1
        }
    ],
    "submitted" : NumberLong(1413385395423),
    "total" : 8000,
    "userId" : "Zq7iMaoT7cBS5dHAv"
}`

I've tried two ways to make this query in mongo:

1. `db.mycollection.findOne( 
                   { $and: 
                       [   { _id: "ZfHCLZF4fC3e99PTs" }, 
                           { dishes: { $elemMatch: { dishId: "ASxbTyAe3CrKuNPF4" } } }
                       ] 
                   } 
               );`
2. `db.mycollection.findOne({ _id: "ZfHCLZF4fC3e99PTs", "dishes.dishId": "ASxbTyAe3CrKuNPF4"});`

This two ways work perfectly (in mongo), but when I try the same inside my Meteor app doesn't return anything, this is the code that I'm using (That is basically the same I use directly in mongo):

1. `mycollection.findOne( 
                   { $and: 
                       [   { _id: "ZfHCLZF4fC3e99PTs" }, 
                           { dishes: { $elemMatch: { dishId: "ASxbTyAe3CrKuNPF4" } } }
                       ] 
                   } 
               )`
2. `mycollection.findOne({ _id: "ZfHCLZF4fC3e99PTs", "dishes.dishId": "ASxbTyAe3CrKuNPF4"})`

> Why doesn't work my code in my meteor app?

Comment: Where is this query running (client, server)? Have you checked to make sure that there is data in the collection where ever you're running this?

Comment: The queries are running server side

Comment: If you have the `_id` why do you need the rest of the query? Just do: `mycollection.findOne('ZfHCLZF4fC3e99PTs')`

Comment: Are you debugging or doing a `console.log` to see that the results aren't returned on your server? Only reason I'm asking is that your queries look right so I'm just trying to pin down the point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, don't know why, I made a meteor reset and all everything work perfectly